# Support logging into Stack Exchange account with LinkedIn

Tags: feature-request, login, openid

LinkedIn is very powerful, and for non Google users that wish to have a single sign-on (SSO) for their communities the LinkedIn login is a must. Will Stack Exchange support it?

Comment: See [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165847/login-via-linkedin): *"LinkedIn supports only OAuth authentication; Stack Exchange supports OpenId for auth instead. Facebook paid SE for auth integration, IIRC. – Martijn Pieters"*

Comment: @Stijn that MSE question was roomba-ed ...

Comment: @rene what does '* roomba-ed*' mean?

Comment: @Script47 the automatic script that deletes old/unattended questions is called the [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), my clumsy way of making that into a verb is by adding "-ed" to the word.

Comment: Well too bad, a linkedin integration would be great :/