# Can we tweak the Roomba help article so it shows up in the Help search?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, help-center, automatic-deletion

The Roomba is the cozy name for the automatic script that removes low scoring questions that are left unattended.

The Roomba has its own page in the Help center [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

However, if you try to search in the help for the word [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=roomba) you get no hits. That is due to the fact that the word "roomba" isn't mentioned anywhere on that page, as was the case with [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That [one got resolved by](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313675/help-center-search-for-mcve-does-not-return-the-mcve-help-page) adding this text at the end of that help article:

> You may have been told to include an MCVE by some helpful commentary, or perhaps even an MVCE if they were rushed; sorry for the initialisms, this is what they were referring to.

Can we do something similar for Roomba? I'm not a native speaker so I don’t want to propose anything witty but these are a few posts for inspiration:

- [Why is the script for deletion called Roomba?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314065/why-is-the-script-for-deletion-called-roomba)
- [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420)

(this question was triggered due to [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339850/support-logging-into-stack-exchange-account-with-linkedin?noredirect=1#comment647699_339850) from [Script47](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2263631/script47))

Comment: I tagged this as FR because only SE staff can tweak those help pages IIRC.

Comment: Let's try to choose a text that doesn't make Shog9 [unhappy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315774/578411) ....

Comment: Well a search engine that doesn't pick up on the URL itself is also not very helpful. Quickest way to improve things is your suggestion though. Google does this just fine: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+roomba&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+roomba

Comment: _In commentatories, we call those automatic deletions Roomba._

Comment: I really thought that the "Roomba help article" was something about the vacuum robots. Glad you started by explaining what it really was.

Comment: As Roomba only makes sense in a North American context, it should be explained.

Comment: @PeterMortensen i don't see the issue. iRobot Roomba robot "vacuums" are present and known of in Denmark as well....

Comment: @JoSSte in any case, it's cultural; when discovering the word on Stack Overflow, I first thought Roomba was a dance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumba

Answer (score -4):

I initially added the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to this request, since it seemed like a straightforward change at first. However, Philippe and our legal team recommended removing the term "roomba".

Ultimately, we decided to change the URL for this Help Center page from `/help/roomba` to `/help/auto-deleted-questions` (e.g. [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions)), and automatically redirect users from the old URL to the new one. We think this more accurately describes the functionality, and avoids inadvertently offending any third parties.

Since it doesn't exactly fulfill your original request, I've retagged this post as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: "auto-deleted-questions" isn't as convenient to type or as catchy as "roomba" was. Perhaps the script needs a new cute name that has no copyright on it..? 

Comment: I'd support a new cute name for it :)

Comment: My first thought is `garbage-collector`, which incorporates a technical joke. I'm concerned that some might find it less-than-kind, though.

Comment: Less 'cute' perhaps a bit less catchy, but with a history nonetheless, how about `sweeper`, borrowed from the Navy's end-of-day duty-call "Sweepers, Sweepers, man your brooms. Give the ship a clean sweep-down both fore and aft! Sweep down all decks, ladders and passageways! Dump all garbage clear of the fantail! Sweepers."

Comment: Funny enough, I probably should have called it that originally @chindraba - the express intent was to take some of the load off the overworked "janitors" who were getting frustrated with the amount of deletion that needed to be done. Roomba had the connotation of "automatic sweeper", but the downside of needing an explanation in waaay too many cases.